# Configure VS Code / Linting to work with Webpack custom resolve modules paths

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code

I have custom paths in my webpack config.

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'), 'node_modules'],
  },
```

However now, when I do imports like:

`import { DropdownInput, Amount } from 'common/components';`

I miss two things:

- navigation does not work (ctrl + click)
- import errors / warning are not caught suggested in IDE

Is there a way to configure VS Code to recognize additional paths from webpack config?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use VS Code, so I can't check if this works, but for vim it is enough to add the paths in your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "common/components": [
                "path/to/common/components",
            ],
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was too fast, didn't see that you are using javascript. But might still be helpful so I leave the answer here.